# How to manage the Ruby Garbage collector with swig

Tags: c++, ruby, swig

I have a C++ interface for which I create ruby bindings with swig. I am able to build those bindings but I have a problem with the Garbage Collector. My ruby code looks like this:

```
parser = HeaderParser.new(source_file, ['/usr/lib'])
parser.parse
functions = parser.getFunctions //Array of Ruby wrapped class named  Function

functions.each do |f|
  puts f.getName
end
```

The problem is that if the garbage collector delete the parser object, all call to Function objects methods result in a Segfault. That because my C++ Function object just use pointer to memory allocated by the Parser object.

I would like to find a way to tell the GC to not free the HeaderParser object while there are Function object used

I have tried to use directive like

```
%trackbobjects
```

and write a ruby mark function for the garbage collector like in the documentation but without success

```
%header %{
  static void mark_HeaderParser(void* ptr) {
  TruckBoris::HeaderParser* hp = (TruckBoris::HeaderParser*) ptr;

  /* Loop over each object and tell the garbage collector
  that we are holding a reference to them. */
  std::vector<TruckBoris::Function> fns;
  fns = hp->getFunctions();
  int count = fns.size();

  for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    TruckBoris::Function fn = fns[i];
    VALUE object = SWIG_RubyInstanceFor(&fn);

    if (object != Qnil) {
      rb_gc_mark(object);
    }
  }
  }
%}
```

**Informations on the C++ interface**
I have a main class that initialize a Clang CompilerInstance and an ASTConsumer:

```
class HeaderParser
{
  public:
    HeaderParser();
    HeaderParser( std::string sourceFile, std::vector<std::string> headersPaths);
    ~HeaderParser();
    ...
    bool parse(bool mainFile = false);
    ...
    std::vector<Function> getFunctions() const;
    ...
private:
    ...
    clang::CompilerInstance m_ci;
    HeaderElements *m_headerElements; // an ASTConsumer
};
```

When the HeaderParser::parse method is called, it parses a source file and fill a vector of Function objects.

Those objects just use FunctionDecl pointers to memory allocated by the compilerInstance in The HeaderParser.

```
class Function 
{
 public:
   Function();
   Function(clang::FunctionDecl * fn);
   ~Function() {}
   std::string getName() const; 
 private:
   clang::FunctionDecl * m_function;
};
```

So Function class methods are constructed like this:

```
std::string Function::getName() const
{
  if(m_function)
    return m_function->getNameInfo().getAsString();
  else
    return std::string();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to simplify all in order tomake this works.

In the HeaderParser class, instead of directly return a `std::vector<Function>` with :

```
std::vector<Function> getFunctions() const;
```

I have used :

```
int nbFunctions() const;
Function getFunction(int) const;
```

and, remove the mark directives, and let swig do the magick. After that I just have to add in my ruby lib file :

```
class Rtruckboris::HeaderParser
  def functions
    fns=[]
    (0..(functions_num() -1)).each do |i|
      fns<<get_nth_function(i)
    end
    fns
  end 
...
```